# Blocking empty strings to be written into SQL database table

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

I have a program that will update a production database on data point change. However, the embedded script in the program performs a blanket update of an entire row, but what I want it to do is just to partially update values in specified columns. I do not have the time to learn the script and make whatever changes I need, so I tried setting the other columns to Not Null in attempt to block the "" values written from the program.

```
ALTER TABLE `scheduling` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Priority` `Priority` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `PurchaseOrder` `PurchaseOrder` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `PartID` `PartID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `OrderQty` `OrderQty` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `DeliveryDate` `DeliveryDate` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `ReadyToRun` `ReadyToRun` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `LF5` `LF5` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `CompletionTime` `CompletionTime` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ;
```

But this method did not work, the values in the database still got overwritten by "" from the script. Is there a way to prevent columns in the database to be overwritten by empty values?

Here is my database table after the blanket update:

[image]

The intention of the update is just to use work order as PK and update the associated completion time.

I've located the update query in the script:

```
method ODBCConnection.Update (row)
{
    local       query = "";
    local       n, len;
    local       value, retval, cols;

    if (!row.__primary_key || !row..(row.__primary_key))
    {
        error ("Update: Row is not identifiable - primary key not set");
    }
    else
    {
        query = string ("update ", row.__table, " set ");

        len = length(row.__columns);
        n = 0;
        with name in row.__columns do
        {
            if (name != row.__primary_key)
            {
                value = row..name;
                query = string (query,
                                n > 0 ? ", " : "",
                                name, " = ", ODBC_ValueString(value));
                n++;
            }
        }
        query = string (query, " where ", row.__primary_key, " = ",
                        ODBC_ValueString (row..(row.__primary_key)));

//      princ (query, "\n");

        .Statement().FreeStmt (SQL_CLOSE);
        retval = .Query (query);
        if (retval != -1)
            retval = .StoreResult();
        else
            error (.Error());
    }
    retval;
}
```

And I changed the query part to:

```
if (name != row.__primary_key)
        {
                            name = "CompletionTime";
            value = row..name;
            query = string (query, name, " = ", ODBC_ValueString(value));

        }
```

That did not work either.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You dont have to learn he whole script. All you have to do is LOOK FOR UPDATE queries

Comment: You have a wierd date in `CompletionTime` as well. Maybe there is more wrong here than you first thought

Comment: The script is not writing NULL to the column, it's writing '' which is why NOT NULL doesn't work. You have to edit your script to just not do that portion... otherwise you'll have to do some convoluted workaround like adding a trigger to put the old value back or something... which I'm not even sure is possible.

Comment: The datetime format in completion time part is fixable it is just an error in the data source.

Comment: As you are building the `UPDATE` statement dynamically, you just have to additionally check in your `while`-loop if the `new value == ""` and in that case skip the update for that column.

Comment: But I do not understand why my changed script is not working...